# how to fix circular references in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, reference, dependencies, circular-dependency

I have a class `Game` has a property `guiGame` which is an instance of GuiGame

```
const Game = function() {this.guiGame = new GuiGame(this) ...}
Game.prototype.onStart = function () {this.guiGame.showCountDown()}
```

the `GuiGame` class also has a property 'game'

```
const GuiGame = function (game){
     this.game = game
}
GuiGame.prototype.onClick = function() {this.game.start()}
```

How can I fix object cyclic dependency for `Game` and `GuiGame`?

Comment: Your code looks reasonable. I don't see anything wrong with that. Circular references aren't inherently a problem.

Comment: What is the reason this needs fixing?

Comment: Because I worry this may led to memory leak

Comment: @TiếnThànhNguyễn: Can you explain how the leak will happen with an example ?  For me, its like a `"Human" can have a "child" property, and "child" can refer to another "Human"`. That's not a problem.